# Calculate average unknown amount of input

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, average

I am doing an ultimate beginner's course in programming, using Python 3. I have to do an assignment. The assignment is the following:

> Write a program in Python that reads numbers from standard input of the Linux shell, and displays the average of these numbers, with one digit after the decimal point. Tip: use the round function with two arguments.

I honestly have no idea how to calculate the sum of an unknown amount of input. Everything I can find is for if you know how many numbers will be input.

So far I have this:

```
import sys

def main():

   print ("To stop entering numbers and calculate average, press CTRL+D")
   print ("Enter numbers:")
   i = 0
   for line in sys.stdin:
       print (i, "\t", line.strip())
       i = i + 1
   sum = i +int(line.strip())
   amount = i
   average = sum / amount
   print(sum)
   print(amount)
   print("The average of the numbers you entered is", round (average, 1),".")

main()
```

but I feel I'm completely on the wrong track there. What happens now is that all the characters in the loop get counted for the sum, so you get

```
4

1  4

6

2  6

2 

3  2

sum 9

average 3

(9/3)
```

But I need, of course, `(4+6+2)/3`.

I am 100% a beginner, I haven't ever done any coding before, and this course is supposed to be for people like me, but I don't believe them any more.

Comment: How is the average coming out to be 3 ?

Comment: The loop numbers each line so if you type 1 and enter next line is 1 1, then 2 enter, next line  is 2 2. All those characters are counted, so that would be 4 characters. As you can see I have nine characters there, but somehow when dividing it does realize that there were only three input-characters, so it divides nine (total) by three (input). I don't know why, unfortunately. Maybe if you copy the code and try it out yourself it will be a bit clearer what I mean. I don't know all the terminology (yet) so I am probably not explaining very clearly.

Comment: i'm not going to answer it, but i'll give you some guidance. first, create a list of all values you get from input as integers. when you've successfully done this, you simply need to sum up that list of numbers and divide by the amount of numbers in the list.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to create a list when I don't know how many values will be inputted (if that isn't a verb, please tell me). I have Googled this to no avail, because I think I don't know the right terminology to use to find the answer I need... I created that loop because I thought that would give me an amount of input (since it numbers everything), but that's not working either because I clearly misunderstood how that works as well. I know I'm coming across as absolutely clueless, but this is the first assignment and I don't know where to get the info I need.

Comment: Put the numbers in a container and use the built-in function [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing average and sum outside the for loop in your code. I just moved them into the for loop. For every iteration , the sum and average both will change, so they have to be in the for loop.

```
print ("To stop entering numbers and calculate average, press CTRL+D")
print ("Enter numbers:")
i = 0 
sum = 0 
average = 0.0 
for line in sys.stdin:
    print (i, "\t", line.strip())
    i = i + 1 
    sum +=  int(line.strip())
    average = sum/i
print("The average of the numbers you entered is", round (average, 1),".")
```

Printing the sum, average values can be done outside the for loop.
This is the correct method

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still not getting the right results. If I use your suggestion the average for inputting 3 5 7 9 somehow becomes 3.2 instead of 24.

Comment: 24 is the sum and 6 is the average. I am getting 6 as my answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I see now that I had left the i + after sum +=

Comment: Thank you! I will look up your changes to make sure I understand what you did.

Comment: You were doing average and sum outside the for loop in your code. I just moved them into the for loop. For every iteration , the sum and average both will change, so they have to be in the for loop. Printing the sum, average values can be done outside the for loop.

Comment: ^ @Bhawandeep: that comment with the explanation is very good, would you merge it into your answer? We like explanation in answers here.

Comment: `i = i + 1`, next line: `sum += int(...)`. Make up your mind